# how do i set programmatically checkbox property 'checked' or 'defaultChecked' in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, checked

i am developing web application with react.

I want to dynamically set 'checked' property on checkbox.

It showed a proper screen that i wanted, but not working when i programmatically set 'checked' property.

So, i have searched about this.

some people recommended to use 'defaultChecked' property.

ant then i tried this. but failed.

It has not changed when i had given event that programmatically set checked property. It always showed defaultChecked value.

source code

```
render() {
list = {
 resource: {[...], [...] },
 ...
}
return (
<ParameterContainer values={ list } />
);
}

    class ParameterContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    render() {
        const { values } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="parameter-table">
                <div className="parameter-row-container">
                    <ul className="parameter-row title">
                        <li className="parameter parameter-1">valid</li>
                        <li className="parameter parameter-2">Key</li>
                        <li className="parameter parameter-3">Type</li>
                        <li className="parameter parameter-4">oid</li>
                        <li className="parameter parameter-5">rid</li>
                        <li className="parameter parameter-6">desc</li>
                    </ul>
                    {
                        values.resource.map((value, i) => {//one row
                            return (
                                <ParameterItem value={ value } index={ i } key={ i }/>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class ParameterItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {
        const { value, index } = this.props;
        const items = [];

        for (let o in value) {
            if (o === "valid") {
                continue;
            }
            items.push(value[o]);
        }
        return (
            <ul className={`parameter-row parameter-row-${ index+1 }`}>
                <li className="parameter parameter-1">
                    <input type="checkbox" defaultValue={ value.valid } checked={ value.valid } onChange={ this.toggle }/> //i tried to this.
                    <Checkbox isChecked={ value.valid } /> // and then tried this...
                </li>
            </ul>
        );
    }

    toggle(e) {
        $(e.target).prop("checked", e.target.checked ? 0 : 1);
    }
}

class Checkbox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            checked: !!this.props.isChecked
        };
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        const { target: { checked }} = e;
        this.setState({ checked });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="checkbox" checked={ this.state.checked } onChange={ this.handleChange } />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `this.state.checked` being correctly displayed?

If the problem is with `handleChange` could you try adding this to your constructor:
`this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Your onChange method in checkbox input is missing a binder.

Try this: `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}`.

More explanation of the usage of `.bind(this)` can be found here: [Handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for controlled components, where the value of the component is dictated by state and updated thru an onchange handler. Check out https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I wanted to list a set of checkboxes, but some of them might be already checked.

I solved it like this:

```
                {this.props.checkboxesList.map(e => (
                  <CustomInput
                    type="checkbox"
                    key={e.id}
                    id={e.id}
                    name={e.nombre}
                    label={e.nombre}                        
                    defaultChecked={
                      this.props.form.selected.filter(
                        item => item.id === e.id
                      ).length === 0
                        ? false
                        : true
                    }
                    onChange={this.props.onCheckBoxChange}
                  />
                ))}
```

**Note**: CustomInput is from 'reactstrap'

And my "onCheckBoxChange" looks like this:

```
   handleCheckBoxChange = e => {
let options = this.state.form.selectedOptions;
if (e.target.checked) {
  options.push({ id: e.target.id, nombre: e.target.name });
} else {
  options = options.filter(item => item.id !== e.target.id);
}
this.setState({
  form: {
    ...this.state.form,
    selectedOptions: options
  }
});};
```

Have into account that "state.from.selectedOptions" must be an array.

Hope it helps